# What's wrong with this JavaScript If statement?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, conditional-statements

I'm trying to build a basic Rock, Paper and Scissors game, can anyone give me a hint as to why this if statement is being rejected.

```
var rps = function(input1, input2){
    if (input1="paper" && input2="rock") {
        console.log("Player 1 wins!");
    };
};
```

Comment: Speaking of giving a hint... http://jshint.com/ :-)

Answer (score 2):

The equality sign should be `==` instead of `=`

```
var rps = function(input1, input2){
    if (input1=="paper" && input2=="rock") {
        console.log("Player 1 wins!");
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, comparison is done using `==` not `=`

Second of all, remove the semicolon at the end of if.

Answer (score 1):

1. If you want to check ifa variable is equal to a value, you have to use "=="
2. name your function!
3. if-statement doesen't need a semicolon!

   function rsp(input1, input2){
       if (input1=="paper" && input2=="rock") {
           alert("Player 1 wins!");
       }
   };

Answer (score 0):

You're assigning not evaluating. This should make a fun Paper, Rock, Scissors Game:

```
var prsStatements = {
  paperBeatsRock: 'Paper Beats Rock',
  rockBeatsScissors: 'Rock Beats Scissors',
  scissorsBeatsPaper: 'Scissors Beats Paper',
  seperator: ' - ',
  player1wins: 'Player One Wins!',
  player2wins: 'Player Two Wins!',
  tie: "It's a Tie!"
}
function prs(in1, in2){
  var p = /^paper$/i, r = /^rock$/i, s = /^scissors$/i, in2r = new RegExp(in2, 'i'), prss = prsStatements, sep = prss.seperator;
  if(in1.match(p) && in2.match(r)){
    return prss.paperBeatsRock+sep+prss.player1wins;
  }
  else if(in2.match(p) && in1.match(r)){
    return prss.paperBeatsRock+sep+prss.player2wins;
  }
  else if(in1.match(r) && in2.match(s)){
    return prss.rockBeatsScissors+sep+prss.player1wins;
  }
  else if(in2.match(r) && in1.match(s)){
    return prss.rockBeatsScissors+sep+prss.player2wins;
  }
  else if(in1.match(s) && in2.match(p)){
    return prss.scissorsBeatsPaper+sep+prss.player1wins;
  }
  else if(in2.match(s) && in1.match(p)){
    return prss.scissorsBeatsPaper+sep+prss.player2wins;
  }
  else if(in1.match(in2r)){
    return prss.tie;
  }
}
```

Now you don't have to worry about case sensitive issues, and your output can be changed!